# nodejs - filter huge json file data

Tags: node.js, algorithm, big-o, file-processing, bigdata

I have two files with book ids

```
- current.json [~10,000 lines]    -> books saved in the system
- feed.json    [~300,000 lines]   -> feed file contents all books from a book store
```

from these 2 files I want to generate 3 files

```
- not_available.json -> books exists in current but not in feed
- to_be_updated.json -> books exists in both current and feed
- new.json           -> books exists only in the feed
```

because **the files are huge** I read the file line by line, **I can't put the data in an array in the memory**

## pseudocode

my code for to do this is as follow

```
// export to_be_updated.json and new.json
feed <- initstream(feed.json)
while(lf <- feed.nextline())
    found <- false;
    current <- initstream(current.json)
    while(lc <- current.nextline())
        if(JSON.parse(lf).id == JSON.parse(lc).id)
            found <- true
            break
    if(found) then append(lf, to_be_updated.json)
    else append(lf, new.json)

// export not_avialbale.json
current <- initstream(current.json)
while(lc <- current.nextline())
    found <- false;
    feed <- initstream(feed.json)
    while(lf <- feed.nextline())
        if(JSON.parse(lf).id == JSON.parse(lc).id)
            found <- true
            break
    if not(found) then append(lc, not_available.json)
```

This code has a time complexity of `O(nm)` for `n = 10,000` and `m = 300,000` and space complexity of `O(1)` so it takes really very long time, for `500mb` it takes about 2hrs using `core i5`

I tried to put the logic in only one nested loop but that wasn't possible. I'm trying to reach better complexity **with unsorted files**

do you think this is the best way to do it ? is there any better approach ?

## update (file format)

feed.json has the following format (example)

```
{"id": "12340", "title": "A life journey", "price": "34.00"}
{"id": "12341", "title": "all over the world", "price": "42.00"}
{"id": "12342", "title": "good to remember", "price": "60.00"}
{"id": "12343", "title": "A night in Mars", "price": "14.00"}
...
```

Comment: Would it be possible to upload the files somewhere? Is using mongodb or sql an option?

Comment: @MartinGottweis the data of `current.json` come from `mongodb`, the has simple format check my update

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream
may help you

Comment: Put the feed json in mongo and with easy querying you will have your lists. In general you will need to order/hash/make a b-tree out of your data for this to be not slow.